# What is the proper way to setup a real, forward transform in pyFFTW?

Tags: python, fft, fftw, pyfftw

According to the documentation of the [`pyfftw.FFTW`](https://pyfftw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/pyfftw/pyfftw.html#fftw-class) class, setting up a `FFTW_FORWARD` transform from `float32` to `complex64` is an excepted [scheme](https://pyfftw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/pyfftw/pyfftw.html#scheme-table).

However, this simple setup example sets of an error:

```py
import numpy as np
from pyfftw import FFTW, zeros_aligned

x = np.random.rand(2**16).astype('float32')

fx_ = zeros_aligned(x.shape, dtype='float32')
Fx_ = zeros_aligned(x.shape, dtype='complex64')

fft = FFTW(fx_, Fx_, direction='FFTW_FORWARD', threads=1)
```

output:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-d3bbc28ef9bf> in <module>
      3 Fx_ = zeros_aligned(x.shape, dtype='complex64')
      4 
----> 5 fft = FFTW(fx_, Fx_, direction='FFTW_FORWARD', threads=1)

pyfftw/pyfftw.pyx in pyfftw.pyfftw.FFTW.__cinit__()

ValueError: Invalid shapes: The input array and output array are invalid
complementary shapes for their dtypes.
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: The `float` to `complex` scheme is a real transform, which means the output array should have a shape as described below the scheme table (specifically, not the same size). Easier is to use the [`builders`](https://pyfftw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/pyfftw/builders/builders.html) API which probably won't compromise your speed at all.

Comment: @HenryGomersall might you be so kind as to add an example?

Comment: @HenryGomersall I mean an example for the shape of the output array `Fx_` in my original post. Timing the `builders` API definitely compromises speed.

Comment: if the builders API substantially slows down the algorithm, that's smells like an error or (much less likely) a bug. Re an example try `Fx_ = zeros_aligned(x.shape[-1]//2 + 1, dtype='complex64')`.

Comment: @HenryGomersall is right! From [the documentation](https://pyfftw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/pyfftw/pyfftw.html#fftw-class) : For a Real transform in the Forwards direction, both the following should be true:

    `output_array.shape[axes][-1] == input_array.shape[axes][-1]//2 + 1`
    All the other axes should be equal in length. It comes from the requirement of [real to complex transform of FFTW](http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/One_002dDimensional-DFTs-of-Real-Data.html).